# i want to add auth based roles like admin and editor users for my dashboard using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, roles, autoresize

hello i want to add autorization roles like admin and editor users for my reactJs dashboard using firebase .
when a user create his own account he will be a editor by default.
in the same time i want to create just one user as an admin so he can do extra things .

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase custom claims which can be used for role based control access.

Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims for more information.